# osmdroid - how to download tiles for offline use?

Tags: download, offline, tiles, osmdroid

My app tries to download tiles for offline use like this:

```
for (MapTile mapTile : tileSet) {   
  mapView.getTileProvider().getMapTile(mapTile);
}
```

However, only a small part of the tileSet is actually downloaded.

How can I download all tiles contained in the tileSet at once?

Comment: What does your `tileSet` consist of? Are you sure it has all the tiles you want?